# webview_flutter cause issues while archive in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-add-to-app, webview-flutter

I have a flutter module and integrated in the existing iOS app (**add to app**).
Everything was working but when I try to Archive it produces an error in **webview_flutter** module:

> bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/flutter-module/.ios/Flutter/engine/Flutter.framework/Flutter' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/flutter-module/.ios/Flutter/engine/Flutter.framework/Flutter' for architecture armv7

I checked the build setting and the Bitcode enabled is set to "Yes" for obvious reasons, what might be the reason for this error? Does it have something to do with the webview_flutter module?

**EDIT**

macOS: 10.15.3 (Catalina)

Xcode version: 11.0 (11A420a)

Flutter version: Channel stable, 1.20.2

Comment: What version of Flutter are you using? As of 1.9.6, Flutter should have bitcode included.

Comment: @Coder-256 I am using 1.20.2, Do you think it is an issue with the package (webview_flutter), because this error occurs within that package.

Comment: I'm not sure yet, but I'm leaning towards no. What Xcode and macOS version are you using? Could you add all the version info into your question?

Comment: Can you check that "Enable Bitcode" is enabled, and everything under "Architectures" is set to the default (not bold) on *all* your targets?

Comment: I have updated the question with versions,  and Bit code is enabled and the "Architectures" are all set to defaults. let me know if you need any further data

Comment: What version of Xcode 11 specifically? Sorry for all these questions

Comment: No problem at all updated the question. Also @Coder-256 I see an open issue for this in the flutter repo https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48092. Though it is not specific to this package.

Comment: Ok, I guess the answer is that this is a known bug and nothing wrong with your code. However one thing I would try is upgrading Xcode to the latest version (currently 11.6).

Answer (score 1):

To archive an iOS app with Flutter module:

1. Run `flutter build ios` in your flutter module directory to create a release build.
2. Return to Xcode, then clean build folder (optional) and perform archive.

This part is not well-documented in Add-to-app section. For more detail, see [create a build archive](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive) in official document.